# "can not fork user shell: Cannot allocate memory"

Tags: linux, centos, putty

When i'm login into my server using putty it log in perfectly but when i try to use : `su` it asks for password. But after a while without login as super user it shows

```
can not fork user shell: Cannot allocate memory
```

How to overcome this situation ?

Comment: also we should check `ulimit -m` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user has processes, kill them. If you can ssh as root (khm..) try that.

Do some investigation to know why does this happened (top/mem/...). Of course you need memory for this so best wishes...

If these fail you have to use the good old ctrl+alt+reset combination :)

Comment: It was a pun. ctrl+alt+delete is fine.